# Scalable implementation of Bitcoin

Tags: scalability

What reference implementations of Bitcoin are most suitable for backing a front end service on to with a high user load?

Something that can be put onto our own AWS or Google Cloud hardware and support being scaled up to support high demand. The front end site will allow people to have their own wallet to pay others for work or product discounts or receive funds for those same things.

One options seems to be Bitcore which has come along way since I last used it. It is Node.JS which can be put on AWS Elastic Beanstalk and it uses MongoDB which can also be scaled on AWS. Are there others and please let me know if I'm wrong about Bitcore before I get too entrenched.

Comment: Here is an interesting article that discusses the issues involved:  https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/the-switch/wp/2013/11/12/bitcoin-needs-to-scale-by-a-factor-of-1000-to-compete-with-visa-heres-how-to-do-it/